# Using Azure's azcopy tool from within a javascript azure function

Tags: javascript, azure

My setup is the following: I have 1 storage account with a container and I have another storage account with a different container. What I want to do is have a blob trigger activate whenever someone uploads a file to the first storage account, and have that blob be copied to the second storage account's container. azcopy works well with the command line, but I have not found a way to use it within an azure function. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For NodeJS, you would just use [Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (or a wrapper like [`execa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa)) to run executables but isn't something I would recommend you do. Also, when running on Azure, you will have to make sure `azcopy` is present and if you still need to go down this path, [Custom Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-javascript) would be your best bet.

In the case of Azure Functions if the file just must be copied to a different container, you could just use the [Blob Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=javascript) which would achieve this with almost no code.

For more complex scenarios where the output binding lacks, you could just use the [Blob Storage NodeJS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs) directly in your code.